# How to extract the `€` character at NSString's given index without the character corruption?

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding

Suppose I have a pool of characters which I can use to generate a random string:

```
NSString* chars = @"-/:;()$&@\".,?!'[]{}#%^*+=_\\|~<>€£¥•abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

and suppose I have generated this string:

```
randomString = @"%[NQ6KC9SL?g£M€J";
```

when I try to extract the Euro character with statement below (when `i` is `14`):

```
NSString* character = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [text characterAtIndex:i]];
```

I get:

```
(lldb) po character
¬
```

`¬` is not `€`.
I suspect it's an encoding problem, but how do I handle it properly?

`£`, for example,  is not causing this kind of issues.

My eventual goal is to tap the `€` character on the screen keyboard with:

```
self.app.keys[character] tap
```

Since the `€` key has a label `label: '€'`, and not `¬`, it's breaking my code.

I have tried to substitute `€` with `\u20AC` in the `chars` pool, but that hasn't fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong formatting character in your `stringWithFormat` -

- `%c` is an 8 bit usigned character
- `%C` is a 16 bit UTF-16 code unit

Refer to [Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)

Change the `%c` to `%C` and your code will work